# php redirect using a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I looked over stack for an answer with no success. Im looking to make a form with radio buttons. Depending on the radio buttons that are checked, pressing the submit button will direct you to a different page. Right now im using php with the get option. However the best im able to do is make dynamic pages based of the get info. Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: PHP can't do this, since PHP executes only on the server and has no control over the client once the page has been loaded. You'll need to use Javascript to dynamically redirect.

Comment: With the GET info, do a conditional statement and use HEADER to redirect someone to the desired page. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 6):

In your PHP you could check `$_GET['radio_option']` and based on the value redirect to other pages using `header` function, something like this:

```
switch($_GET['radio_option']) {
case 'val1':
    header('location: page1.php');
    exit;
case 'val2':
    header('location: page2.php');
    exit;
case 'val3':
    header('location: page3.php');
    exit;
}

//here handle everything else - although normally you shouldn't get here
```

The other alternative would be to use javascript to set the `action` attribute of the form before it is submitted.  For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio[name=your_radio_naem]").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var target = "main.php";

        if(value == 'val1')
            target = "page1.php";
        else if(value == 'val2')
            target = "page2.php";
        else if(value == 'val3')
            target = "page3.php";

        $('#myform').attr('action', target);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to set each radio button with a value of the redirect page.

```
$page=$_GET['radio_buttons'];
header('location: $page');
```